# Jmeter- Condition using response assertion

Tags: jmeter

How to put a condition using response assertion in jmeter.

In loadrunner we have web_reg_find with savecount attribute. This helps us to for keeping condition in IF loop.

```
if textcount >0
  transaction --> pass
else
  transaction--> fail and exit iteration and continue
```

Similarly, how to get the count of text check and place the same in condition (IF loop) in jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

Use any of the post processor extractor to fetch all the values in a variable. Like in regular expression we can use "-1" in "match no." to fetch all the values matching with the regular expression. So, you will get the count.
Now, put that as a condition in if controller like ${__groovy("${countVar}"=="10")}

In short,

1.Add a [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as a child of the request to fetch all values.

2.Add If Controller at the same level to check the condition.

More information: [6 Tips for JMeter If Controller Usage](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage)

Answer (score 0):

1. If you provide "Match No" as `-1` in the Regular Expression Extractor

   [image: JMeter Regex Matches]

   you will have `${foo_matchNr}` variable containing the number of matches.

   [image: JMeter Variable Value]
2. Since [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4) you have [__isVarDefined() function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__isVarDefined) which can be used to check whether a JMeter Variable is defined or not

   [image: JMeter isVarDefined]

Both approaches can be used in the [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller)